# How could I switch from an array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to route set of array, but it's not working.

```php
<?php
$routes = array('home'=>'Home Page','about'=>'About Me');
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
switch($action) {
  foreach($routes as $key => $value) {
    case $key:
      echo $value;
      break;
  }
}
```

But instead, it returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "foreach", expecting "case" or "default" or "}"`

Comment: Please take a look at how [php switches work](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). The `foreach` should be *inside* the `case`.

Comment: Forget about switch and foreach… `echo $routes[$action]`…!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve it this way, with using filter_input on get variable:

```
<?php
$routes = array('home'=>'Home Page','about'=>'About Me');
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
if ($action) {
  echo $routes[$action];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, even if you could, I would advise against it as it is not a conventional practice.

Why not just use something like the following?

```php
<?php
$routes = array('home'=>'Home Page','about'=>'About Me');
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
if (array_key_exists($action, $routes)) {
  echo $routes[$action];
} else {
  // Do you error handling here.
}
```